# Perl regex: Substitution of everything but the pattern

Tags: regex, perl, substitution

In perl, I would like to substitute a negated class character set (everything but the pattern) by nothing, to keep only the expected string.  Normally, this approach should work, but in my case it isn't :

`$var =~ s/[^PATTERN]//g;`

the original string:

```
$string = '<iframe src="https://foo.bar/embed/b74ed855-63c9-4795-b5d5-c79dd413d613?autoplay=1&context=cGF0aD0yMSwx</iframe>';
```

wished pattern to get:  `b74ed855-63c9-4795-b5d5-c79dd413d613`

(5 hex number groups split with 4 dashes)

my code:

```
$pattern2keep = "[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12}";
```

(should match only :  xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx (5 hex number groups split with 4 dashes) , char length :  8-4-4-4-12 )

The following should substitute everything but the pattern by nothing, but in fact it does not.

```
$string =~ s/[^$pattern2keep]//g;
```

What am I doing wrong please? Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

A *character class* matches a **single** character equal to any one of the characters in the class. If the class begins with a caret then the class is negated, so it matches any one character that isn't any of the characters in the class

If `$pattern2keep` is `[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12}` then `[^$pattern2keep]` will match any character other than `-`, `0`, `1`, `2`, `4`, `8`, `9`, `[`, `]`, `a`, `f`, `{`, or `}`

You need to capture the substring, like this

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

my $string = '<iframe src="https://foo.bar/embed/b74ed855-63c9-4795-b5d5-c79dd413d613?autoplay=1&context=cGF0aD0yMSwx</iframe>';

my $pattern_to_keep = qr/ \p{hex}{8} (?: - \p{hex}{4} ){3} - \p{hex}{12} /x;

my $kept;

$kept = $1 if $string =~ /($pattern_to_keep)/;

say $kept // 'undef';
```

#### output

```
b74ed855-63c9-4795-b5d5-c79dd413d613
```

Comment: Thank you, it works!  This is a nice trick doing a capture of a substring instead of doing a negated string substitution.

Comment: @TomášLučenič: I don't know where you got the idea of a "negated string substitution". There is no such thing.